# VLC: adding media files to playlist via cmd using wildcards

Tags: cmd.exe, vlc-media-player

I use  VLC 3.0.11 for Windows x64 and want to add media files to a new playlist via cmd using wildcards.
For example:

```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" ??? "*.ts"
```

What should I use instead of **???** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I use instead of **???** ?

I am not aware of a native VLC option that would include only files of a certain type. Based on the [command line documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) (also available with e.g. `vlc -H`), the closest option in VLC seems to be `--ignore-filetypes` which allows the *exclusion* of certain files by extension ex.:

```
vlc --ignore-filetypes=jpg,log,m3u,cue "C:\path to files"
```

---

*Note that as far as I can tell, `--ignore-filetypes` seems to only be applied when VLC initially starts. Running a second VLC call with `--one-instance` and `--playlist-enqueue` but different `--ignore-filetypes` extension parameters appeared to have no effect during testing in VLC 3.0.11 on Windows (July 2020).*

---

**Using A Script**

With that said, building off the comment you placed on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/623821/302907), you may be able to achieve your goal with a script based around VLC's `--one-instance` and `--playlist-enqueue` options and e.g. Windows [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7):

*ex. vlcq.ps1*

```
# Use basic wildcard notation (ex. "*.mp3") to place
# matching file names from a directory into a VLC
# playlist.

# Set to ex. "C:\path to files\*.mp3" via the command-line
$playlist_path = $args[0]

# Turn ex. "C:\path to files\*.mp3" into ex. "C:\path to files\*"
$playlist_directory = Split-Path -Path $playlist_path
$playlist_directory = $playlist_directory + '\*'

# -Leaf returns the last item or container in a path
# (ex. "*.mp3")
$file_type = Split-Path -Path $playlist_path -Leaf

# Place any matching file names/paths into a $file_list
# $file_list = Get-ChildItem C:\path to files\* -Include *.mp3
$file_list = Get-ChildItem $playlist_directory -Include $file_type

# "Pre-load" VLC for (arguably) better intial playback, etc.
# Start-Process vlc -ArgumentList '--one-instance'
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -ArgumentList '--one-instance'

foreach ($file in $file_list) {

    # Add quotes to $file output, since this may contain spaces.
    $quoted_file_path = '"' + $file + '"'

    # Queue up the item in the current VLC playlist.
    # Start-Process vlc -ArgumentList '--one-instance', '--playlist-enqueue', $quoted_file_path
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -ArgumentList '--one-instance', '--playlist-enqueue', $quoted_file_path

    # Add a delay between loading files to help avoid playlist
    # jumbling. May not be 100% effective.
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

    }
```

Where:

- `$args[0]` is a PowerShell variable containing the first command line value after the script name (ex. a path\wildcard combination like `C:\path to files\*.mp3`).
- `\*` is appended to `$playlist_directory` to ensure the `-Include` option of [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) works correctly (without a final `\*`, an empty list may be produced).

---

*Note that this script assumes a single playlist play-through. Unfortunately, looping didn't seem to work consistently for me.*

---

**Usage**

Copy the script above and save it as ex. `vlcq.ps1`. You can use whatever file name you like but make certain to save it as a `.ps1` (PowerShell script) file.

Assuming you opened a command window in the same directory as the saved `.ps1` script (above), you could then load files into a VLC playlist with wildcards as follows ex.:

```
powershell -file .\vlcq.ps1 "C:\path to\*.mp3"
```

Note that you may need to [enable PowerShell script execution](https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts) before running the command above.

**Helper Batch**

If the command above is a little long to type, you can wrap it in a batch file e.g.:

*ex. vlcq.bat*

```
@ECHO Off

powershell -file "C:\path to\vlcq.ps1" %*
```

then simply run ex. `vlcq "C:\path to\*.mp3"` in the same directory as e.g. `vlcq.bat`. If you want ex. `vlcq` (a.k.a `vlcq.bat`) available anywhere from the command line, you can always [place it in a folder in your Windows path](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

**Path Notes**

- The path to pass to the script for items in the current local directory would be `.\` (ex. `.\*.mp3`).
- `*.mp3` is just an example. This syntax should work for any media type (i.e. `*.ts`). Note that this script has a potential side benefit in that it can queue up multiple images from a directory (which doesn't seem normally possible with just ex. `vlc "C:\path\to\images"`).
- If you provide a non-existent extension, etc. (i.e. you use `*.mp3` with a directory that contains no `.mp3` files), VLC will start (via the first `Start-Process` command), but no files will be added to the playlist.
- You can use `*.*` but be aware that this will do exactly what it says. That is, it will load all the files in the directory (including any non-media files).
- You can select items other than by extension with simple Windows regex (e.g. `A*.mp3` will select `.mp3` files starting with `A`).
- When passing paths to the script above, some file paths that contain non-standard characters (ex. `[]`) may not load correctly, even if they are generally not an issue in Windows.

**Caveats**

- Remember that the `Start-Process` commands in the PowerShell script above need a valid path to VLC (assuming VLC isn't available from the command line as just `vlc`).
- Beware of playlist jumbling. In short, calling VLC for each file (via `ForEach` and `Start-Process`) may result in some files being loaded out of order in the current playlist (compared to their order in the directory). Using a delay of e.g. 2 seconds after each call to load a file (via `Start-Sleep -Seconds 2`) seems to *mostly* alleviate this, but it may still be possible that some files could be loaded out of order (depending on VLC load times).
- Though initial automatic playback shouldn't be affected, delaying file loading means that loading all the items in a directory may take some time (in the background) compared to e.g. simply opening a directory with ex. `vlc "directory name"` (which is nearly instantaneous). As a practical side effect, closing VLC before the script has loaded all these files will cause VLC to reopen and begin playing whichever file was last loaded by the script.
- Regarding the `powershell` command, neither double-quotes around paths nor the `-file` option to `powershell` are technically needed if a path does not contain spaces, but paths with spaces will *not* work correctly without them (you will get a playlist full of essentially invalid items).
- If you add any options to the basic `powershell` command above, `-file` should be the final option provided.

---

*PowerShell References*

- *[Split-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)*
- *[ForEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Start-Sleep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7)*

Comment: Great answer! I really appreciate this.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help. =)

Comment: A suggestion to simplify this script: Separating out the path and file type is not actually necessary: I changed it to simply say `$file_list = Get-ChildItem $args[0]` -
This handles all the wildcards automatically, and also handles scenarios like running vlcq *.wav in the current directory which gave me troubles with the script as is...

Answer (score 1):

(powershell)

To quickly open up the files in vlc (you can save them to file using the GUI later):

```
(ls *.ts) | %{vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue $_}
```

To first save to file, then load in vlc:

```
(ls *ts).FullName | Out-File -Encoding ascii index.m3u -Append
vlc index.m3u
```

I prefer the former as it allows me to rearrange the file order if needed.