# VLC on raspberry pi - how to play all images/videos in a folder from command line without showing terminal, and how to set time per image?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc-media-player, raspbian, slideshow

I'm trying to build an automated slideshow player which allows the user to copy multiple videos and images into a folder on the RPI and play them on a loop.

I'm running Raspbian Lite (no GUI) latest version.

I'm currently running the command (based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/623804/how-to-play-a-folders-worth-of-music-video-in-vlc-media-player))
`vlc --loop --playlist-autostart --one-instance /foldername/*.*

This plays the images and videos, but with the following problems:

1. It doesn't loop.
2. There is no way to set the time to display each png/jpg image.
3. Between images, the terminal becomes visible.

Is there a way to correct these issues?

Comment: How is it possible to play VLC videos though Raspbian Lite (no GUI is key here) without any mention of x11 forwarding?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you can play videos with VLC directly to the HDMI screen even without X installed.  Try it!

Comment: Thanks for the info Mr Ryan, I didn't know that! :)